# Import C headers in Swift

Tags: ios, malloc, swift

I cannot import `malloc/malloc.h` to use `malloc_size()` to see the size of an object. Is it available in `Swift` or am I doing it wrong: `import malloc/malloc.h`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Unix/POSIX stuff is all in the `Darwin` module.

```
import Darwin

let r = rand()
qsort_b(buffer, 0, 10, sortFunc)
```

`malloc` is in there, too, but it won't do you much good — it returns an opaque pointer.

Comment: How would you figure this out if you didn't know it? Is there a list of the modules that you can import by default?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into using a bridging header?

Create a .h file named -Bridging-Header-File.h
Then reference it in your projects build settings (under "Swift Compiler" look for "Objective C Bridging Header") with:

```
$(SRCROOT)/<Your-Project-Name>-Bridging-Header.h
```

Now malloc_size() should be available

Answer (score 0):

You can't import C headers. In order to import a C Library (or Objective-C framework) in Swift it has to be in a module. I'm not aware of a module that contains malloc though.

Comment: Ok, and how do I create this module and what is a module?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know much about modules, but the clang docs do tell you the requirements for creating a module: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html

Comment: XCode 6 does allow to create a user defined module, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use "malloc_size"? You do not need to import "malloc.h" to do that, assuming you're either including Foundation or Cocoa.

This works just fine in a playground:

```
import Foundation

let chars = BytePtr.alloc( 1000 )
let qty_of_bytes_allocated = malloc_size( chars )

println( qty_of_bytes_allocated )
```